# TV series with a Team

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror, hard-sci-fi

I remember watching a tv series back in 2008-2009 where theres a group of young girls and boys. They fight monster that come to the city and that comes in their way. I kinda remember the name as *Monster Warriors* , but I can't find the tv series. 
I remember there was an episode of it where there comes a giant worm inside a mall and these guys fight it.

Not sure if it was a movie though, but I lean more on the tv series side.

Comment: Any idea what channel/network? Actors? Country of origin? This is a pretty lean question and additional details would be very helpful.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: A TV series? With a *team?* That’s crazy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right about its name.

from  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Warriors):

> Monster Warriors is an original Canadian television series which aired on YTV in Canada and also on Jetix since April 2006 in the United Kingdom. It was created by Wilson Coneybeare and produced by Coneybeare Stories Inc. The series concluded its run on July 26, 2008, with a TV movie titled Monster Warriors Finale on YTV.

The wiki also mentions the monster described:

> Worm – An earthworm that eats subway trains.

This episode is called *The Terror Underground*.