# Cartoon TV show aired in UK where creatures would be supersized as enemies, fought by a group of teens/young adults

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I distinctly remember it being a *Monster Hunter*-style cartoon TV show I watched in the UK, most definitely after 2000. Usually in each episode, a mad scientist-type guy would make creatures gigantic (usually insects, like I remember a spider and maybe a wasp/bee?), and then a group of teens(?)/young adults(?) would have to save the day.

The only thing that really comes up when trying to search this is *Godzilla* cartoons but I think I would remember watching a *Godzilla* cartoon as the name is so familiar.

I used to always think it was called *Monster Hunters* or something in that vein but that name doesn't lead me anywhere useful.

Comment: How did these teens/young adults defeat the giant bugs? Mechs, vehicles, weapons, etc

Comment: Was it the same mad scientist every time?

Comment: @KMo: with tea, biscuits, and healthy dollops of pluck and gumption I’ll wager.

Answer (score 4):

*Monster Warriors* (2006) seems to fit pretty well... Apart from it being live-action, and not a cartoon (though the awful CGI is cartoonish).

The [National Library of Australia](https://trove.nla.gov.au/work/35621345?q&versionId=44331926) covers the "giant" part:

> What's going on in Capital City? Major monster trouble is what is going on. An earthworm so enormous it's eating trains, a giant squid that's munching whole fishing boats, a giant ice monster who can freeze you with one breath.

And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Warriors) covers the "mad scientist" part:

> The series, a purposely campy cross between the Power Rangers and Ghostbusters, follows the adventures of **four teenagers fighting to safeguard Capital City from the vengeful wrath of insane and disgruntled old B-Movie director Klaus Von Steinhauer who possesses the ability to bring his cinematic monsters to life ("I make ze monsters big!")**. Over the course of the series, various story arcs occur that expand the series cast and city locations. Each week sees the teens customize common household objects into useful weapons to fight against monstrous creations.

Checks:

- big monsters, created by a mad scientist-type guy (check out the first shot of the opening below)
- monsters come in various tastes, but the [episodes​ list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Warriors#Episodes) has its share of insects, with a carnivorous butterfly, bumblebees, termites, stinkbugs​...
- the monsters are fought by teenagers
- title resembles *Monster Hunters*, aired after 2000

Doesn't check:

- it's not a cartoon... *But*, what passes for "special effects" is so bad it's borderline cartoonish (see [these stinkbugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9rlg.png))

---

Remembered from [TV series with a Team](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/196574) which I recalled was IDed as "Monster something".